# Find points on the surface of a Graphics3D object

Tags: graphics3d, list-manipulation

If I have a Graphics3D object that was generated from manipulations to PolyhedronData rather than via an explicit equation, for example the Spikey 
[image: Spikey 6!]

(for which the entire code can be found here [*The Cover Image: Making the Mathematica 6 Surface-Textured Hyperbolic Dodecahedron*](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6712/#downloads), but which culminates with the following command,

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], 
  addHatToL /@ Take[Flatten[Take[LsOnDodecahedron, All]], All]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Full, 
 Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[0.2, 0, 0]}, {"Point", 
    RGBColor[0.4, 0.4, 0.4], {2, 0, 2}}, {"Point", 
    RGBColor[0.4, 0.4, 0.4], {2, 2, 2}}, {"Point", 
    RGBColor[0.4, 0.4, 0.4], {0, 2, 2}}, {"Point", 
    RGBColor[0.2, 0, 0], {-2, -2, -2}}}]
```

Is there a way for me to extract/generate a table of 3D points along the surface of (or within, I don't actually care) the object?

I saw [*Efficiently determining if 3D points are within a surface composed of polygons*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20105/efficiently-determining-if-3d-points-are-within-a-surface-composed-of-polygons), which went a bit over my head, but many of the answers given seemed to either require a 'nice' shape (i.e., no concave surfaces, no cusps, no self-intersections, etc.) or be based on the fact that he had generated the object with generated data sent to ListContourPlot3D, which is not the case here.

Comment: I assume you're aware of this, but the vertex coordinates of the original `PolyhedronData` object are accessible like this: `PolyhedronData["GreatStellatedDodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"] // N`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pull out the points by searching for `Polygon` objects in `addHatToL /@ Take[Flatten[Take[LsOnDodecahedron, All]], All]`:

```
p1 = addHatToL/@Take[Flatten[Take[LsOnDodecahedron, All]], All];
surfacepoints = Flatten[Flatten[Cases[Flatten[p1[[#]]],Polygon[m_] ->m], 1]&/@Range[Length[p1]], 1];
```

`surfacepoints` will then give you the points on the surface of the original picture.