# Meshing the cow

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

As a simple example for applying stl-files I took "cow" out of MMA example data. I'm able to discretize the Graphic without problems

```
kuh = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}]
mesh=DiscretizeGraphics[kuh,MeshCellStyle -> {{1, All} -> Red}] (* MeshRegion *)
```

[image]

to get an stl-like triangle surface, which seems to be ok

```
ConstantRegionQ[mesh]
(*True*)
```

for further meshing, but my attempt to create a volumemesh fails

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
ToElementMesh[RegionBoundary[mesh]]
(*$Failed*)
```

What's wrong with my attempt?
Thanks!

Comment: Just drop the `RegionBoundary` and it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately no:  `ToElementMesh[mesh] (*$Failed*)`

Comment: I have verified it, it works for me on MMA 11.3 (Windows). And it also works online in "Programming Lab"

Comment: Did you know that you can just do `ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}, "MeshRegion"]`?

Comment: @  J. M. is computer-less No I didn't, thanks.

Comment: @ Piniti Thanks, it seems to be a problem of MMA version  11.0.1

Comment: However, `FindMeshDefects[ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}, "MeshRegion"]]` shows that a conversion to a volume mesh might not be straightforward.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The cow mesh is an example of a "broken" mesh. Try

```
mesh =  RepairMesh[mesh]
```

before sending it to `ToElementMesh`.

Among other nice meshes, you can find a free and "clean" cow mesh also on Keenan Crane's homepage:

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/ModelRepository/

This is the model (without texture):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but nothing changes: `meshR = RepairMesh[mesh ];
ToElementMesh[meshR] (*$Failed*)`

Comment: @Ulrich, running `FindMeshDefects[meshR]` should show what may be causing the failure.

Comment: Apparently version 11.3 can cope both with the unrepaired and the repaired mesh. So I don't know what to do. The mesh has self-intersections so tet-meshing it is nontrivial.

Comment: Obviously the example isn't as simple as I hoped for. Thank you Henrik and J.M.

Comment: @Ulrich By the way, a good and clean mesh is the `"Triceratops"`.

Comment: @ Henrik Thanks, I'll try ...

Answer (score 8):

As other's have stated, the issue is self intersecting facets:

```
mr = RepairMesh[ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}, "MeshRegion"]];

FindMeshDefects[mr]
```

[image]

If we could determine if a point is 'inside' the cow, we could use a naive variant of the powercrust algorithm. Here 'inside' is not necessarily well defined.

Luckily we can use `isInside` defined specifically for this model [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/116179)!

```
dm = DelaunayMesh[MeshCoordinates[mr]];

powercrust = BoundaryMesh @ MeshRegion[
  MeshCoordinates[dm], 
  Pick[MeshCells[dm, 3], isInside /@ PropertyValue[{dm, 3}, MeshCellCentroid]]
];

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

ToElementMesh[powercrust]
```

> ```
> ElementMesh[{{-0.410816, 0.410816}, {-0.133851, 0.133851}, {-0.251619, 0.251619}}, {TetrahedronElement["<" 25368 ">"]}]
> ```