# "The function DiscretizeGraphics is not implemented for GraphicsComplex" confusion

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry, version-10

Why does `DiscretizeGraphics` seems to work on one `GraphicsComplex` and not the other? Here is an example that works:

```
v = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}};
p1 = Graphics[GraphicsComplex[v, Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4}]]];
DiscretizeGraphics[p1]
```

But this does not

```
p2 = Graphics3D[First@ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t],  Sin[u], c Sin[t]}, 
   {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]];
DiscretizeGraphics[p2]

(*The function DiscretizeGraphics is not implemented for \
 GraphicsComplex[{{0.9999999999998993`,4.487989505128125`*^-7,*)
```

But `p2` is a GraphicsComplex? Looking at `FullForm[p2]`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the `FullForm` for `p1`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Are not  `p1` and `p2` both `GraphicsComplex` ? `p1` is `2D` and `p2` is `3D`, but are they not both considered `GraphicsComplex`?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It will good to know exactly what can and what can not be discretized. I tried to find this, but could not. All what I see are examples of usages so far.

reference: http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/data-and-mesh-regions/discretizing-graphics.html

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeGraphics.html?q=DiscretizeGraphics

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I also looked at possible issues, and did not notice anything about this. Only one that came close is this `multiple volume primitives is not supported`. Is this the case here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the end this is a bug and I filed that.

Now, what is going on: If you extract the coords and polygons from the `GraphicsComplex` and try to set up a `MeshRegion` you get a warning:

```
gc = First@
   ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[u], Sin[t]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 
     2 Pi}];
ply = Cases[(gc)[[2]], _Polygon, Infinity]
MeshRegion[gc[[1]], ply]
MeshRegion::coplnr: "The vertices in the polygon Polygon[{{1129,1621,705,100}}] are not coplanar."
```

I guess that is what is happening internally and then the conversion is rejected. It could have given a better message, though.

All of the Graphics(3D) functions were written before the `MeshRegion` functionality became available and used their own mesh format. For graphics it is not too important that the underlying mesh is of a good quality (e.g. no non coplanar elements). They human eye is very forgiving in that sense. But for computations over meshes it is essential that the underlying mesh has a reasonable quality. In this case the `ParametricPlot3D` needs to get rid of those non coplanar elements.

To get a discretized cylinder could use

```
DiscretizeGraphics[Cylinder[]]
```

[image]

Comment: If a mesh is made of element with faces non coplanar (to some extent) the PDE solutions I compute with that mesh can be affected? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85592/how-to-create-an-elementmesh-of-a-sphere

Comment: @unlikely, possibly, that might introduce errors at the boundary that ruin the solution; but that's hard to say without seeing an example.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a workaround for this I've been using:

```
p2 = Graphics3D@First@ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[u], Sin[t]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we discretize:

```
DiscretizeGraphics[Normal[p2 /. (Lighting -> _) :> Lighting -> Automatic]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]