# How to create an ElementMesh of a Sphere

Tags: mesh, finite-element-method

I want to create an `ElementMesh` of a "sphere". To reduce the computational effort I want to **use  `HexahedronElement`**; the resulting mesh can have a hole at the center.

The first steps is to create a boundary `ElementMesh` of a spherical surface using `QuadElement`. Then we can project this mesh toward the center of the sphere building successive spherical shells.

What I did is to create a mesh of a circumscribed cube and then project the coordinates on the sperical surface.

Some preliminary definitions:

```
deepLookup[assoc_,listOfLists_,levelspec_:{-2}]:=Map[Lookup[assoc,#]&,listOfLists,levelspec];
partitionOp[spec__][list_]:=Partition[list,spec]
flattenOp[spec_][list_]:=Flatten[list,spec]
partOp[spec__][list_]:=Part[list,spec]
```

The surface density of the mesh (in the real case `n` can be large: 4000, 8000 and more for example):

```
n = 5;
m = 2 n + 1;
cl = Range[-1, 1, 1/n] // N
```

> {-1., -0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0., 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.}

*Update*: Even better:

```
cl = Tan@Range[-\[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/(4 n)] // N;
```

> {-1., -0.726543, -0.509525, -0.32492, -0.158384, 0., 0.158384, 
>   0.32492, 0.509525, 0.726543, 1.}

The "structured" list of coordinates on the cube:

```
pts = Table[
   Tuples[MapAt[#[[{f}]] &, {cl, cl, cl}, {d}]], {d, 3}, {f, {-1, 1}}];
pts = pts // flattenOp[2] // partitionOp[m] // partitionOp[m];
Dimensions[pts]
```

> {6, 11, 11, 3}

Building the quads on each of the six faces of the cubes:

```
coords = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[pts, 2];
assoc = AssociationThread[#, Range@Length@#] &@coords;
incidents = deepLookup[assoc, pts, {-3}];
faceIncs = 
  incidents // Map[partitionOp[{2, 2}, {1, 1}]] // 
    flattenOp[{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4, 5}}] // 
   partOp[All, All, All, {1, 3, 4, 2}];
```

Now project the coordinates on the sperical surface:

```
coords = Normalize /@ coords;
```

and make a flat list of quads incidents:

```
quadIncs = Flatten[faceIncs, 2];
```

A plot of the result:

```
Graphics3D[
 GraphicsComplex[
  coords, {FaceForm[Opacity[.8, LightGray]], 
   EdgeForm[Darker@Gray], Polygon@quadIncs}],
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

*Equidistance*

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Update: Equiangular*

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I can also create successfully the mesh:

```
mesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> coords,
   "BoundaryElements" -> {QuadElement@quadIncs}
   ];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The (possible) problem is that the vertices of each `QuadElement` are not coplanar.

```
assoc2 = AssociationThread[Values@assoc, coords];
coplanarMeasure[
  pts_ /; MatrixQ[pts, NumericQ] && Dimensions[pts] == {4, 3}] := 
 Det[Append[1] /@ pts]
coplanarMeasure /@ deepLookup[assoc2, quadIncs] // Histogram
```

*Equidistance*

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Update: Equiangular*

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[Ancillary question. How this situation is handled by Finite Element framework?  How this situation can affect the quality of the solution returned by `NDSolve`?]

Suppose I want to adjust the coordinates of the mesh so that the vertices of `QuadElement` are coplanar and the resulting mesh is the best approximation of the spherical surphace (in some sense).

How this can be done?

Comment: there is no inherent requirement of the finite element method that quad element faces must be exactly planar.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps this is what you want:  The only trick is scaling the coordinates of each point to lie on the sphere inscribed in the cube symmetric about the origin circumscribing the point.

```
cube = ToElementMesh[Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> {"Volume" -> 0.005}];

rescale[v_] := Max[Abs@v] Normalize[v]

emesh = ToElementMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> rescale /@ cube["Coordinates"],
   "MeshElements" -> cube["MeshElements"]];

emesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm[Directive[Opacity[0.7], LightGray]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is a fast and interesting approach to get the result I called "Equidistance" for a filled sphere; with some change I think I can use for my needs instead of my more complex approach. But the real problem is what I wrote at the end: the vertices of each `QuadElement` or the faces of `HexahedronElement` are not coplanar. Is this a problem for FEM? How can I adjust their positions to fix?

Comment: @unlikely It doesn't seem to be a problem for `NDSolve[]`.  Is there an example where it is?

Comment: @unlikely. No, that should not be a problem.