# ElementMesh (rendering?) issue

Tags: graphics, mesh, finite-element-method

The appearance of the following `ElementMesh` is bad as you can see for example on the inside surface of the shell. The same problem happens converting to a `MeshRegion` (conversion does not warn about problems).

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
em = Import[
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/wc9nd0kyf55t9bg/ElementMeshRenderingIssue.mx?dl=1"]
em["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "MeshElements", 
  "ElementMeshDirective" -> 
   Directive[Specularity[.2], EdgeForm@GrayLevel@.5, 
    FaceForm@GrayLevel@.7], 
  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", GrayLevel[0.45]}, {"Directional", 
     GrayLevel[0.3], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}, {"Directional", 
     GrayLevel[0.33], ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", 
     GrayLevel[0.3], ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I don't understand  if this is just a rendering problem or there is also a problem in the underlying mesh.

I have built this mesh by myself. As I stated in [another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85592/how-to-create-an-elementmesh-of-a-sphere?s=1%7C1.1186) the vertices of the `QuadElement` are not exactly coplanar, and I don't know how to adjust the coordinates so that they eventually become coplanar.

I  noticed some strange behavior using this mesh to solve a PDE with FEM: this can be another clue of some problem with the mesh.

To summarize I want to try to understand

1. if the visualization problem is caused by some problem with the mesh construction
2. if the problem is related with the non-exactly-planar faces, if there is some way to adjust

Any idea on how to proceed? Thanks

---

After more investigation, and thanks to @user21, I discovered that the problem of the failed `ToBoundaryMesh`/`ToElementMesh` roundtrip is probably related to the fact that the mesh uploaded and shown here is no a "complete" spherical shell (this is what I want for a figure to illustrate the process of mesh creation).

The mesh I use as a domain for my PDE is a complete spherical shell, so this should not be the reason why I get strange result when solving over this mesh.

I made another simpler mesh with the same algorith, starting with just 1 face of the cubed sphere (i.e. to get 1/6 of the spherical shell), and with a coarse grid.

```
mesh = Import[
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/46e93mbacvgn2i6/\
ElementMeshRenderingIssue2.mx?dl=1"]
```

I also made a function to extract only part of this mesh.

```
ElementMeshExtract[mesh_, mkform : {memkform_, bemkform_, pemkform_}, 
  idform : {meidform_, beidform_, peidform_}] :=
 Module[{elems},
  elems = MapThread[
    Cases[#1, type_[el_, mk_] :> With[{sel = MatchQ[#2] /@ mk},
        If[! Or @@ sel, Nothing, type[Pick[el, sel], Pick[mk, sel]]]]
      , {1}] &, {mesh /@ {"MeshElements", "BoundaryElements", 
       "PointElements"}, mkform}];
  elems = MapThread[
    Cases[#1, 
      type_[el_, mk_] :> With[{sel = MatchQ[#2] /@ Range@Length@el},
        If[! Or @@ sel, Nothing, type[Pick[el, sel], Pick[mk, sel]]]]
      , {1}] &, {elems, idform}];
  incidents = Union@Flatten@DeleteCases[elems, {}][[All, 1, 1]];
  assoc = AssociationThread[incidents, Range@Length@incidents];
  elems[[All, All, 1]] = 
   Map[Lookup[assoc, #] &, elems[[All, All, 1]], {-2}];
  ToElementMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> mesh["Coordinates"][[Keys@assoc]],
   "MeshElements" -> elems[[1]],
   "BoundaryElements" -> elems[[2]],
   "PointElements" -> elems[[3]]
   ]
  ]

ElementMeshExtract[mesh_, mkform : {_, _, _}, idform_] := 
 ElementMeshExtract[mesh, mkform, {idform, idform, idform}]
ElementMeshExtract[mesh_, mkform_, idform : {_, _, _}] := 
 ElementMeshExtract[mesh, {mkform, mkform, mkform}, idform]
ElementMeshExtract[mesh_, mkform_, idform_] := 
 ElementMeshExtract[
  mesh, {mkform, mkform, mkform}, {idform, idform, idform}]
ElementMeshExtract[mesh_, mkform_] := 
 ElementMeshExtract[mesh, mkform, _]
```

Putting all together in a `Manipulate` I still cannot find anything wrong with that mesh that could explain the bad rendering or the strange results od `NDSolve`.

```
Manipulate[(
  lmesh = 
   ElementMeshExtract[
    mesh, {Alternatives @@ Range@layers, Except@_, Except@_}];
  lc = Total[Length@*First /@ lmesh["MeshElements"]];
  pmesh = 
   ElementMeshExtract[lmesh, _, {i_ /; 1 <= i <= progress, _, _}];
  Column[{
    Show[
     MeshRegion[pmesh, Method -> {"CoplanarityTolerance" -> -100}],
     ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> lmesh["Bounds"], 
     Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> False}],
    BoxWhiskerChart[ElementMeshQuality[pmesh],
     BarOrigin -> Left, BarSpacing -> $MachineEpsilon,
     PlotLabel -> "Quality", AspectRatio -> 1/4, 
     PlotRange -> {{0.5, 1}, Automatic},
     Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, True}}, 
     GridLines -> {Automatic, None},
     ImageSize -> Small]
    }, Center]
  ),
 {{lmesh, lmesh}, None}, {{pmesh, pmesh}, None}, {{lc, lc}, None},
 {{layers, 2}, 1, 5, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{progress, Floor[lc/2]}, 1, lc, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Please provide the code that created `em`.

Comment: Does it change when you make a simpler mesh (less elements, thinner shell, etc...)?

Comment: `Min[em["Quality"]]` seems fine.

Comment: This reveals that there is a problem in the boundary of the mesh: `bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[em]; ToElementMesh[bmesh]` as it fails to generate a tetrahedralized mesh.

Comment: @bbgodfrey In the linked question I provided a simplified version of the code I use to create the spferical surface. The code I use to create the spherical shells is very long and complex because of the "wedge" elements and of many edge cases. I'm not sure if I can extract and post a simplified enough version.

Comment: @user21 Thanks for your investigation. About the visualization, the problem is reduced with a simpler mesh, but doesn't disappear. Also is reduced when I OMIT "wedge" elements or when I place these elements in the middle of the shell. Omitting the "wedge" elements *and* completing/closing the spehere allow to do the `ToBoundaryMesh`/`ToElementMesh` roundtrip. To summarize I think these wedge elements pose a problem (that I need to investigate in some presently unknown way) but is note the only one. If you have some idea on what to search for... Thanks for pointing me in this direction.

Comment: Try to extract the `"BoundaryElements"` and the coordinates from the `em` and put them in a `(Boundary)MeshRegion`; possibly with a `Method->{"CoplanarityTolerance"->XY}` option and see if that shows which boundary elements are not right.

Comment: Try to reduce the number of total element in the mesh, use a smaller region and/or try to have only one layer above and below the wedge elements, if possible.

Comment: @user21 I'll try. There is maybe an easy way to extract elements by markers o create a sub-mesh by markers?

Comment: `MeshElementSplitByMarker[mesh["MeshElements"]]`

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @user21 I think I understood the reason why `bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[em]; ToElementMesh[bmesh]` fails: I think it's "just" because the mesh I uploaded and shown in the picture is not a complete spherical shell, so the boundary elements (created by me) are incomplete. So this should not be an issue when dealing with the whole shell in `NDSolve`. But fixing this doesn't fix the visualization problem. No other definitive result for now unfortunately.

Comment: @user21 What is the default setting for CoplanarityTolerance and what a more tight setting? I tried many values but I don't get any error. Thanks

Comment: I think the default tolerance is around 10^-8.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: @user21 Unfortunately no. Still unclear if it's just a rendering issue or can be the cause of some strange solution from `NDSolve`. At present I had to move on something else and I had to use a mesh without density refinement and "wedge" elements. Later I hope I have time to return on this.