# Volume of HexahedronElement with non-coplanar faces

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs, mesh, finite-element-method

**Bug fixed in Version 12.0**

---

I would like to calculate the volume of `ElementMesh` made of `HexahedronElement`. Even though `"MeshOrder"` is 1, elements can have "curved" faces (nodes of the same face are not co-planar). This is a MWE with one element.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

mesh = ToElementMesh[
  "Coordinates" -> {{0,0,0},{1,0,0},{1,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,0.5},{1,0,1},{1,1,1},{0,1,1}},
  "MeshElements" -> {HexahedronElement[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}]}
  ];
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm[LightBlue],ImageSize -> 200]]
```

[image: hexElement]

I have found 4 different methods and each gives me a different answer. The most straightforward is to use the `"MeshElementMeasure"` method of `ElementMesh` object.

```
Total@Flatten@mesh["MeshElementMeasure"]
(* 0.916667 *)
```

I converted the hexahedron to 5 tetrahedra and called the same method on them (function is defined bellow).

```
Total@Flatten[HexToTetrahedron[mesh]["MeshElementMeasure"]]
(* 0.833333 *)
```

Then my own implementation of Gauss integration of Jacobian determinant over element (function is defined below).

```
MeshElementVolume[mesh["Coordinates"], HexahedronElement, 1]
(* 0.875 *)
```

And finally `NIntegrate` which also works on `ElementMesh` objects.

```
NIntegrate[1., {x, y, z} ∈ mesh]
(* 0.876271 *)
```

What is "the most" correct way to calculate this volume? I know there are some assumptions involved on how to treat the curved face, but surely there must some common way to do this?

---

Definitions of functions used above:

```
HexToTetrahedron::type="ElementMesh should contain only hexadedral elements.";

HexToTetrahedron[mesh_ElementMesh]:=Module[{
    nodes,origElms,tetConnect,restructure,newElms
    },
    origElms=mesh["MeshElements"];

    If[Head@First[origElms]=!=HexahedronElement,Message[HexToTetrahedron::type];Return[$Failed]];

    tetConnect={{4, 1, 2, 5},{7, 5, 2, 6},{4, 2, 3, 7},{4, 5, 2, 7},{4, 5, 7, 8}};
    restructure=Function[{hexNodes},Part[hexNodes,#]&/@tetConnect];

    newElms=TetrahedronElement[
        Flatten[restructure/@First@ElementIncidents[origElms],1]
    ];

    ToElementMesh[
        "Coordinates"->mesh["Coordinates"],
        "MeshElements"->{newElms}
    ]
]
```

---

```
(* Works for one element only. *)
MeshElementVolume[nodes_List,type_,meshOrder_]:=Block[{
    igCrds=ElementIntegrationPoints[type,meshOrder],
    igWgts=ElementIntegrationWeights[type,meshOrder],
    shapeDerivative=ElementShapeFunctionDerivative[type,meshOrder],
    jacobian,r,s,t
    },

    jacobian=Function[{r,s,t},Det[(shapeDerivative@@{r,s,t}).nodes]];

    (jacobian@@@igCrds).igWgts
]
```

Comment: Good to learn about `ElementShapeFunction`! Thanks!

Comment: That looks a bit like a short coming in the hex mesh measure computation.

Comment: @user21 Do you mean it is a bug? Or somehow expected inaccuracy? Do you know what method is behind it?

Comment: It's split into tets but the assumtion is that the faces are planar. I'll need to think about  a more general way to do it. This will take a bit of thought. MeshRegion does warn about this: `MeshRegion[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 
   0.5}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}, 
 Hexahedron[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}]]` Sorry about that.

Comment: I have looked a bit at this and the fix is probably to disallow ElementMesh to have non-coplanar faces. Allowing it will lead to all sorts of problems for other codes. For example: `tmesh = ToElementMesh[ToBoundaryMesh[mesh], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity];
tmesh["Wireframe"]
Total[tmesh["MeshElementMeasure"], 2]
0.8333333333333334` and there is no way to fix that. What do you think?

Comment: Would you mind if I change the title to '... with non coplanar faces' ?

Comment: @user21 But can you really constrain hexahedron elements to have coplanar faces? Wouln't that invalidate some assumptions in FEM?  Maybe it is enough to just document this ambiguity? As long as we use same function for volume calculation at least the comparisons will be valid, I guess.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, do you have an opinion on this?

Comment: @Pinti I don't think that this would break any theoretical assumptions, at least if you employ tri-linear parameterization of quads (the approximation order would remain the same). It makes it just harder to discretize a given geometry. However, tri-quadratic parameterization should be able to approximate the boundary of the domain by an additional order and you would loose this additional order if you require the boundary faces of hexes to be planar.

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103468/18437) is an example that would not work. You'd then need to use something like this :`ToElementMesh[Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Volume" -> 0.005}, 
  "MeshElementType" -> TetrahedronElement];`

Comment: Addendum: When approximating the domain with hexes with planar faces, one may of course not expect the vertices to lie exactly on the boundary. So for 4 points on the boundary, one had to do an SVD or something to find the affine plane that contains the face of the hex to build. And if the considered piece of the boundary is sufficiently smooth, the planar face should essentially have the same (low) approximation order as the bilinear path defined by the 4 points. But of course, I could be wrong.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, yes there would need to be some tolerance. I guess that tolerance can be fairly low, as the current code produces reasonable results if a certain number of elements is used. There case here is an extreme since it's only one element.

Comment: OK, I just merged a fix for this. The "MeshElementMeasure" will now produce a correct result. This is going to be available in the next release (V12). After that, I plan to add a check for co-planarity and give a warning if surfaces are not coplanar. Something like "CheckCoplanarity"->Autotmatic. False would then skip this test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The volume integral over the standard cube (to my surpise, it's `Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}]`) can be computed analytically like this:

```
pp = Table[Compile`GetElement[p, i, j], {i, 1, 8}, {j, 1, 3}];
f = {r, s, t} \[Function] Evaluate[
    ElementShapeFunction[HexahedronElement, 1][r, s, t].pp
    ];
det = Det[D[f[r, s, t], {{r, s, t}, 1}]];
coeffrules = CoefficientRules[det, {r, s, t}];
vol = Values[coeffrules].Table[
    Integrate[
     FromCoefficientRules[{c -> 1}, {r, s, t}],
     {r, -1, 1}, {s, -1, 1}, {t, -1, 1}
     ], 
    {c, Keys[coeffrules]}];
cvol = With[{code = vol}, Compile[{{p, _Real, 2}},
    code,
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True
    ]];
```

Now let's try it:

```
hexdata = Partition[
   mesh["Coordinates"][[Flatten[mesh["MeshElements"][[1, 1]]]]],
   8
   ];
cvol[hexdata]
```

> {0.875}

Comment: I think this is essentially the same method as in my third example. Thanks for showing me a faster code, maybe I can make it work for all element types.

Comment: You can find the base coordinates of the mother element with: `Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
order = 1;
eleType = HexahedronElement;
MeshElementBaseCoordinates[eleType, order]`

Answer (score 5):

Interestingly enough, if you convert the mesh to second order, the correct result comes up. So I made a mess in the 1st order symbolic code.

```
m2 = MeshOrderAlteration[mesh, 2];
m2["MeshElementMeasure"]
{{0.875`}}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed in version 12.0

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 
      0, 0.5}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}, 
   "MeshElements" -> {HexahedronElement[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
        8}}]}];
Total@Flatten@mesh["MeshElementMeasure"]
0.875`
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the shape of a curved 2-dimensional facet cannot be determined by vertex' positions only. In other words, given 4 points in 3D space, there are infinitely many surfaces enclosed by a "frame" (made by connecting the vertices with straight line segments). Thus the volume occupied by your 3D element is not well defined, as the element itself is not well defined.

That being said, I think different code samples you presented produce a **correct** result for **some** 3D element with the vertices specified.

From [Grandma' Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_polygon):
"The interior surface (or area) of such a polygon is not uniquely defined."

Enjoy your FEM!

Comment: Yes and no. For finite elements you use a certain space of local shape functions for the interpolation of functions and implicitly, also for transforming the standard cube/quad/tet/triangle to the actual element. These parameterizations however need a certain number of degrees of freedom. For a hex for which only the corner vertex coordinates are known, the canonical parameterization is by tri-linear interpolation. _Then_ the geometry of the element is uniquely defined as the image of this parameterization.