# Making holes from maze generated Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d, finite-element-method, mesh

```
Get["IGraphM`"]
maze = IGRandomSpanningTree[IGMakeLattice[{5, 5, 5}], 
  VertexCoordinates -> Tuples[Range[5], {3}], VertexShape -> None, 
  EdgeStyle -> CapForm["Round"], 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> (Cylinder[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]]}, 0.2] &), 
  VertexShapeFunction -> (Ball[#1, 0.2] &)]
showmaze = 
 GraphPlot3D[maze, EdgeRenderingFunction -> (Cylinder[#1, .2] &), 
  VertexRenderingFunction -> ({ColorData["Atoms"][
       RandomInteger[{1, 117}]], Sphere[#1, .2]} &)]
```

[image]

I've generated the bone of a maze here, but I want to make it carved out in a cube, so it's really a maze.

I've tried
(1) Exporting showmaze to stl, re-importing to get a MeshRegion(which I don't know how to display), and apply RegionDifference
[image]

but it fails. 
[image]

(2) Try to make a hole from the showmaze, but I cannot find any reference on how to do this.

Comment: If you want people to run your code post it as text, not images; the latter are too difficult to cut and paste into a notebook.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's an approach that unions the primitives as rasters, meshes, and smooths.

Data from OP:

```
showmaze = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode @@ ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVJcP.png"], "Byte"]];
```

Primitives with an extended inlet and outlet:

```
prims = CapsuleShape @@@ Cases[showmaze, _Cylinder, ∞];
prims = prims /. {{5., 5., 5.} -> {5.5, 5., 5.}, {1., 1., 1.} -> {1., 0.5, 1.}};
```

Now let's rasterize the model. To ensure a quality rasterization, I'll rasterize each capsule separately and join them together:

```
ims = RegionImage[#, {{0.3`, 5.7`}, {0.3`, 5.7`}, {0.3`, 5.7`}}, RasterSize -> 100] & /@ prims;
im = ImageApply[Max, ims]
```

[image]

We'd like the complement of this image:

```
im = ImageTake[ColorNegate[im], {5, -5}, {5, -5}, {5, -5}]
```

[image]

Now mesh the data. Here I've clipped to show inside:

```
Show[bmr = ImageMesh[im, Method -> "DualMarchingCubes"], PlotRange -> {{0, 91}, {1, 92}, {0, 91}}]
```

[image]

This looks pretty good, ***and for applications like 3D printing it’s very much sufficient***, but there are some artifacts we could smooth. One approach is to use `GraphDiffusionFlow` defined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172603/4346), but I was unable to find parameters that smoothed out the caps nicely.

Instead I've gone ahead and implemented a version of the approach outlined [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c04a/52ad1287385b18464b61f190d1888bf95efd.pdf). The code for this is at the bottom of the post.

```
cube = smoothMeshRegion[bmr];
```

This looks a bit better, however the outer part of the cube has very soft edges:

```
{cube, Show[cube, PlotRange -> {{-1, 91}, {1, 93}, {-1, 91}}]}
```

[image]

We can fix this by clipping:

```
cube = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[smoothed, {{1, 91}, {1, 91}, {1, 91}}];

{cube, Show[cube, PlotRange -> {{1, 90}, {2, 91}, {1, 90}}]}
```

[image]

Finally a wireframe view:

```
BoundaryMeshRegion[cube, MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> {Thin, Black}}, PlotTheme -> "Lines"]
```

[image]

---

### Edit

I couldn't resist printing this maze

[image]

and solving it with food coloring.

[image]

[image]

---

### Code Dump

```
(* https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c04a/52ad1287385b18464b61f190d1888bf95efd.pdf
   Note: the paper suggests to work with the face centroids. I saw no discernible difference between using them or just the face vertices, so for speed and ease of implementation I'm going with the former.  *)

Options[smoothMeshRegion] = {"FeatureVertices" -> Automatic, "LaplacianMatrixMethod" -> Automatic, "VertexPenalty" -> Automatic};

smoothMeshRegion[mr:(_MeshRegion|_BoundaryMeshRegion), OptionsPattern[]] :=
    Block[{coords, cells, n, L, findices, Fdiag, μ, F, m, A, b, At, ncoords},

        (* ------------ mesh data ------------ *)

        coords = MeshCoordinates[mr];
        cells = MeshCells[mr, 2, "Multicells" -> True];
        n = Length[coords];

        (* ------------ Laplacian matrix ------------ *)

        Switch[OptionValue["LaplacianMatrixMethod"],
            "UniformWeight", L = UniformWeightLaplacianMatrix[mr],
            Automatic|"Contangent"|_, L = CotangentLaplacianMatrix[mr]
        ];

        (* ------------ vertex penalty matrix ------------ *)

        {findices, μ} = featureVertices[mr, OptionValue["FeatureVertices"]];

        Fdiag = vertexPenalty[coords, OptionValue["VertexPenalty"]];
        Fdiag = ReplacePart[Fdiag, Thread[findices -> μ]];

        F = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Fdiag]];
        m = Length[F];

        (* ------------ global matrix ------------ *)

        A = Join[L, F];

        (* ------------ right hand side ------------ *)

        b = ConstantArray[0., {Length[A], 3}];
        b[[n + 1 ;; n + m]] = Fdiag * coords;

        (* ------------ solve the system ------------ *)

        At = Transpose[A]; 
        ncoords = Quiet[LinearSolve[At.A, At.b, Method -> "Pardiso"]];

        (* for large enough μ, ensure the feature vertices are truly fixed *)
        If[TrueQ[μ >= $μ],
            ncoords[[findices]] = coords[[findices]]
        ];

        (* ------------ construct mesh ------------ *)

        Head[mr][ncoords, cells]
    ]

CotangentLaplacianMatrix[mr_] :=
    Block[{n, cells, prims, p1, p2, cos, cots, inds, spopt, L},
        n = MeshCellCount[mr, 0];
        cells = MeshCells[mr, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]];
        prims = MeshPrimitives[mr, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]];

        p1 = prims - RotateRight[prims, {0, 1}];
        p2 = -RotateRight[p1, {0, 1}];
        cos = Total[p1 p2, {3}] Power[Total[p1^2, {3}]*Total[p2^2, {3}], -0.5];
        cots = .5Flatten[cos*Power[1 - cos^2, -.5]];

        inds = Transpose[{Flatten[cells], Flatten[RotateLeft[cells, {0, 1}]]}];

        Internal`WithLocalSettings[
            spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"];
            SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total}],
            L = SparseArray[inds -> cots, {n, n}],
            SetSystemOptions[spopt]
        ];

        L = L + Transpose[L];
        L = L - SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> Total[L, {2}]}];

        L
    ]

UniformWeightLaplacianMatrix[mr_] :=
    Block[{C00, W, II},
        C00 = Unitize[#.Transpose[#]]&[mr["ConnectivityMatrix"[0, 2]]];
        W = SparseArray[-Power[Map[Length, C00["MatrixColumns"]] - 1, -1.0]];
        II = IdentityMatrix[Length[C00], SparseArray];

        SparseArray[(C00 - II)W + II]
    ]

$μ = 5.0;
$λ = 0.5;

featureVertices[mr_, fv:Except[{_, _?Positive}]] := featureVertices[mr, {fv, $μ}];
featureVertices[_, {None, μ_}] := {{}, μ};
featureVertices[mr_, {Automatic, μ_}] := {Union @@ Region`InternalBoundaryEdges[mr][[All, 1]], μ}
featureVertices[_, {vinds_, μ_}] /; VectorQ[vinds, IntegerQ] && Min[vinds] <= 1 := {vinds, μ}
featureVertices[_, {_, μ_}] := {{}, μ};

vertexPenalty[coords_, λ:(Automatic|_?NumericQ)] := ConstantArray[If[TrueQ[NonNegative[λ]], λ, $λ], Length[coords]]
vertexPenalty[coords_, vpfunc_] := vpfunc[coords]
```

Comment: @Hurst: I produced all of the above output, except the last line (BoundaryMeshRegion[cube, ...]) produced a black square brick.  Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: It's a slightly large mesh and so the line thicknesses might be blending together on your screen. Try adding in `ImageSize -> 1024` or some similar large value.

Comment: That was the answer, only the image is still fairly dark.  I used ImageSize -> (1024+512) and it looks more nearly like yours only much bigger.  Thanks.

Comment: @ChipHurst A+ GIF (and of course A+ answer)

Comment: Super cool print job. SLS process?

Comment: Thanks. It was on an SLA printer.

Comment: Wow! If only I have a printer like that! Best solution so far!

Answer (score 24):

Lets start by making a symbolic representation of maze, with `BooleanRegion` using graphic primitives. That will be our basis for discretization by any method. Number of vertices of graph should be small to make experimentation easier.

```
(* "IGraphM" package downloaded from https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM *)
Get["IGraphM`"]

n = 3; (* Number of vertices per dimension. *)

IGSeedRandom[42]; (* Set random seed for repeatability. *)
mazeGraph = IGRandomSpanningTree[
  IGMakeLattice[{n, n, n}],
  VertexCoordinates -> Tuples[Range[n], {3}]
]

maze = GraphPlot3D[
  (* Convert it to directed graph, to avoid double rendering of edges. *)
  DirectedGraph[mazeGraph, "Acyclic"],
  EdgeRenderingFunction -> (Cylinder[#1, .2] &),
  VertexRenderingFunction -> (Ball[#1, .2] &),
  Axes -> True
]
```

Add definition for outer box, entry point and exit point. Then show them together with maze graphics.

```
cuboid = Cuboid[{0., 0., 0.}, (n + 1) {1., 1., 1.}];
entry = Cylinder[{{1., 1., 0.}, {1., 1., 1.}}, 0.2];
exit = Cylinder[{{n, n, n}, {n, n, n + 1}}, 0.2];

Show[
 Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Red], entry, FaceForm[Green], exit}],
 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Black]], FaceForm[], cuboid}],
 maze,
 Boxed -> False
]
```

[image: MazeGraphics]

Extract a list of graphic primitives `Cylinder` and `Ball`.

```
primitives = Join[
  Cases[maze, _Cylinder | _Ball, Infinity],
  {entry, exit}
];
```

Create symbolic `BooleanRegion` where each primitive is subtracted from outer box.

```
reg = Fold[
   RegionDifference,
   cuboid,
   primitives
]
```

Here I have tried to use functions `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` and `DiscretizeRegion` on `reg` with different option values for `Method` and `AccuracyGoal` but nothing worked. It seems to me that currently Mathematica (v11.3) can't handle discretization of such (complex) 3D regions.

---

I can offer alternative solution which uses [Gmsh](http://gmsh.info/) software for discretization our `BooleanRegion`. I have created package [GmshLink](https://github.com/c3m-labs/GmshLink) with very basic functionality, but just enough to solve our problem.

```
(* Load the package and then set path to Gmsh executable. *)
Get["GmshLink`"]
$GmshDirectory = "local/path/to/directory/with/gmsh.exe";
```

Then use `ToElementMesh` function with custom mesh generating function `GmshGenerator`.

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[
  reg,
  RegionBounds[cuboid],
  "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> None,
  "ElementMeshGenerator" -> {GmshGenerator, "OptimizeQuality" -> False},
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.2
]
```

It produces tetrahedral mesh of decent quality (for FEM purposes). `"OptimizeQuality"` can be set to `True` to get mesh with better quality, but this takes more time.

```
Through[{Min, Mean}@Flatten[mesh["Quality"]]]
(* {0.165972, 0.724565} *)

mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: MazeMesh1]

Discretization via Gmsh is not too slow and I think it would be possible to create maze for `n=5`, just go easy on `MaxCellMeasure`. Resulting `ElementMesh` can be converted to to `MeshRegion` if neccesary.

```
mr = MeshRegion[mesh]
```

---

We can group `"BoundaryElements"` according to their normals, assign markers to them and use this for nice visualization.

```
applyBoundaryMarkers[mesh_ElementMesh,tolerance_?NumberQ]:=Module[
    {grouping,bElms,markers},

    grouping=GroupBoundariesByNormals[mesh,Clip[tolerance,{0,1}]];
    bElms=First[mesh["BoundaryElements"]];
    markers=ReplaceAll[
        Range@First[grouping],
        Dispatch@(Join@@MapIndexed[
            Thread[#1->First[#2]]&,
            Last[grouping]
        ])
    ];

    ToElementMesh[
        "Coordinates"->mesh["Coordinates"],
        "MeshElements"->mesh["MeshElements"],
        "BoundaryElements"->{Head[bElms][ElementIncidents@bElms,markers]},
        "PointElements"->mesh["PointElements"]
    ]
]
```

Use the above defined function on tetrahedral mesh. Grouping tolerance is adjusted manually.

```
meshWithMarkers = applyBoundaryMarkers[mesh, 0.5];
meshWithMarkers["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} *)

meshWithMarkers["Wireframe"[
  Or @@ Thread[ElementMarker == {1, 4, 5, 7}],
  "MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements",
  "MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm@*Lighter /@ ColorData[112, "ColorList"]
]]
```

[image: MazeMesh2]

Comment: This is great! Note that you need to condition your code on `$OperatingSystem` in a few places. On MacOS, the executable is simply `gmsh`, not `gmsh.exe`. Also the function `quotes` is not needed for Unix based operating systems, so `If[$OperatingSystem === "Windows", quotes[str_String]:="\""<>str<>"\""; quotes[other_]:=other, quotes = Identity];`

Comment: Awesome! Keep up the good work!

Comment: @ChipHurst pointed out that you can shave off some time by setting "BoundaryMeshGenerator"->None if you do not make use of the "BoundaryMesh" in the numerical region in the interface.

Comment: This answer is more than what I was expecting, but when I tried to add an entrance and exit, it stopped working, halting at the evaluation. The mesh generation is for FEM, and probably overkill/too complicated for general processing, and I'm hoping that there is still a better method.

Comment: @seilgu Please check updated answer. I added maze entrance and exit geometry and some options to speed up mesh generation.

Comment: @ChipHurst and user21 Thank you for really helpful suggestions!

Comment: "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> None,
    "ElementMeshGenerator" -> {GmshGenerator, "OptimizeQuality" -> False},

These are new? Now it's a lot faster. Thanks!

Comment: @Pinti Very cool!

Answer (score 10):

OK, I just learned a bunch from the question and @Pinti's answer, thanks!

As an experiment, this generates a maze with rectangular passageways. The good news is you can stay in Mathematica to the finish line. Start same as @Pinti, but just generate the maze, not worrying about cylinders.

```
n = 4;
maze = IGRandomSpanningTree[IGMakeLattice[{n, n, n}], VertexCoordinates -> Tuples[Range[n], {3}]];
```

Grab the adjacency list and the positions of the vertices, and get a list of undirected edges. I am sure I am kludging this. Also set the "radius" for the passageways.

```
al = AdjacencyList[maze];
vs = (AbsoluteOptions[maze, VertexCoordinates] // Values // First);
undir = Union@(Sort /@ Flatten[MapIndexed[Outer[List, ##] &, al], 2]);
radius = .1
```

Get the cuboids that follow the edges. They currently overlap each other.

```
cubmazeInner = Map[
              Cuboid[vs[[First@#]] - radius {1, 1, 1}, vs[[Last@#]] + radius {1, 1, 1}] &, 
              undir, 1];
```

Define the entry, exit, and enveloping cuboid as per @Pinti, and add the entry and exit to the list of Cuboids that make the maze.

```
entry = Cuboid[{1., 1., 0.} - radius {1, 1, 1}, {1., 1., 1.} + radius {1, 1, 1}];
exit = Cuboid[{n, n, n} - radius {1, 1, 1}, {n, n, n + 1} + radius {1, 1, 1}];
cuboid = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, (n + 1) {1, 1, 1}];

cubmaze = Join[cubmazeInner, {entry, exit}];
```

Take a look. Reminds me of where people pour molten metal into ant colonies.

```
res = BooleanRegion[Or, cubmaze];
Show[
    Graphics3D[res],
    Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Black]], FaceForm[], cuboid}],
    Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Probably because of the cuboidal nature of the geometry, Mathematica can get us all the way to the finish line at this point. Using @Pinti's method, which did not work for the cylindrical passageways...

```
reg = Fold[RegionDifference, cuboid, cubmaze];

RegionPlot3D[reg, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3]]
```

[image]

You can spin it around and see inside it. Very cool. Exported it to STL and imported it to CAD, and it looks fine. Tempted to try to print one.

Note that this did *not* work...

```
internals = RegionUnion[cubmaze];
reg = Fold[RegionDifference, cuboid, internals]; (* DID NOT WORK *)
reg = RegionDifference[cuboid, internals]; (* NOPE *)
```

One more time with `n=8`. Maybe a minute for the full computation.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Version 12.1 has an [OpenCascadeLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html). Generating the geometry with this is another alternative:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

showmaze = 
  Uncompress[
   FromCharacterCode @@ 
    ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVJcP.png"], "Byte"]];
prims = Cases[showmaze, _Cylinder | _Ball, Infinity];
prims = prims /. {{5., 5., 5.} -> {5.5, 5., 5.}, {1., 1., 1.} -> {1., 
      0.5, 1.}};
cuboid = Cuboid[{1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, {5, 5, 5} + 1/2];
Graphics3D[{prims, {Opacity[0.3], cuboid}}]
```

[image]

Generate the symbolic region:

```
reg = Fold[RegionDifference, cuboid, prims];
```

Use the open cascade boundary mesh generator:

```
bounds = Transpose[List @@ cuboid];
AbsoluteTiming[
  bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[reg, bounds, 
    "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"OpenCascade"}]
  ];
```

Visualize the boundary mesh with all boundaries grouped:

```
groups = bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp;
bmesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> (Directive[{FaceForm[#], EdgeForm[]}] & /@ 
     colors), PlotRange -> {{0, 5.4}, {0, 5.4}, {0, 5.4}}]]
```

[image]

You can then generate the full mesh:

```
AbsoluteTiming[mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh]]
(* {22.961911`, 
 ElementMesh[{{0.5`, 5.5`}, {0.5`, 5.5`}, {0.5`, 
    5.5`}}, {TetrahedronElement["<" 963565 ">"]}]} *)
```