# Minimal surface bounded between turns of helix

Tags: finite-element-method, computational-geometry, differential-geometry

I'm curious to find the shape of a surface bounded between the rungs of a helix, ie the shape of the cloth stretched between the rungs of this child's play tunnel. I'm wondering if we could find it like how we find minimal surfaces: it seems like a tilted but asymmetrical catenoid.

I tried to find this surface using the code posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72340/88731) but it returns a helicoid. How do I "restrict" the code to find the minimal surface bounded *between* the rungs? (ie a hollow centre)

[image]

**Further question**

To verify whether the surfaces produced by @Greg's code are minimal surfaces, I compared an analytical catenoid to the surface obtained when passing an identical cylinder through `areaGradientDescent`.
However, I noticed a sharp edge that wasn't minimised:
[image]

Which could be the reason why the obtained surface is more "minimised" than the catenoid (the outer surface is the analytical solution):
[image]

How do I fix this?
*Update: this is resolved by using the original `areaGradientDescent`*

**Comparison with analytical solution**

As suggested, here are 3 different mesh refinements:
[image]
From left to right, `MaxCellMeasure->{"Length"->0.1, 0.01, 0.005}`. The outer one is the analytical solution for a catenoid of the same radius.
Comparing the areas, the refined solution returns 5.98 (the increased refinement only changes the area from 5.983 to 5.979) while the analytical is 6.12. While the error may not be very large, about 2.3%, I'd like to understand how the numerical errors arise. Thanks so much!

Comment: I guess you generated the cylinder by a `ParametricPlot3D`. Then it is rectangular surface piece rolled to a cylinder, but the seems are not glued together. My code will then treat all the edges along that seem as boundary which is why the points there are fixed.

Comment: Oh I see! After inspecting the mesh further I noticed the straight edge, using back `areaGradientDescent` gives the smooth result. However the above observation that it "overminimises" the surface still holds unfortunately...

Comment: How much does it "overminimise"? This effect should dissappear with finer and finer meshes.

Comment: The effect doesn't seem to be disappearing for the range of refinement that my computer can handle...I'm curious to understand how the errors arise and how we could possibly improve it. Thank you so much!

Comment: To address your 'further question'. How did you generate the cylinder? My guess is there's a topological boundary along the length of the tube. `FindMeshDefects` could possibly hint this to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another approach is to modify `areaGradientDescent`, defined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158356/4346), to fix user specified edges in space.

```
areaGradientDescentFixedEdges[{R_MeshRegion, fixededges_List}, stepsize_: 1., steps_: 10, 
 reassemble_: False] := 
Module[{method, faces, bndedges, bndvertices, pts, intvertices, pat,
  flist, A, S, solver}, 
 method = If[reassemble, "Pardiso", "Multifrontal"];
 pts = MeshCoordinates[R];
 faces = MeshCells[R, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]];
 bndedges = Union[
   Join @@ MeshCells[R, {1, fixededges}, "Multicells" -> True][[All, 1]], 
   Developer`ToPackedArray[Region`InternalBoundaryEdges[R][[All, 1]]]
 ];
 bndvertices = Union @@ bndedges;
 intvertices = Complement[Range[Length[pts]], bndvertices];
 pat = Flatten[getLaplacianCombinatorics[faces], 1];
 flist = Flatten[faces];
 Do[A = LaplaceBeltrami[pts, flist, pat];
  If[reassemble || i == 1, 
   solver = LinearSolve[A[[intvertices, intvertices]], Method -> method]];
  pts[[intvertices]] -= stepsize solver[(A.pts)[[intvertices]]];, {i, 1, steps}];
 S = MeshRegion[pts, MeshCells[R, 2], PlotTheme -> "LargeMesh"];
 S
];
```

And then take a similar approach to my other answer here:

```
helixPoints[l_, p_, r_, z0_:0] := Table[{r*Cos[2π/p * θ], r*Sin[2π/p * θ], z0 + θ}, {θ, 0.0, Round[l/p, 0.025p], 0.025p}]

minimalHelixTube[l_, p_, r_] :=
  Block[{helix1, helix2, n, m, mr, ldist, fixed, mrminimal},
    helix1 = helixPoints[l+4p, p, r, -2p];
    
    n = Length[helix1];
    m = Round[1/0.025];
    
    mr = MeshRegion[
        helix1,
        Polygon[Join @@ ({{#1, #1-m, #1-m+1}, {#1, #1-m+1, #1+1}}& /@ Range[m+1, n-1])]
    ];
    mr = DiscretizeRegion[mr, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.1}];
    
    ldist = RegionDistance[MeshRegion[helix1, Line[Range[n]]]];
    fixed = Pick[
      Range[MeshCellCount[mr, 1]], 
      Threshold[ldist[AnnotationValue[{mr, 1}, MeshCellCentroid]]],
      0.0
    ];
    
    mrminimal = areaGradientDescentFixedEdges[{mr, fixed}, 0.25, 20, False];
    
    DiscretizeRegion[mrminimal, {{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {0, l}}]
  ]
```

And test:

```
minimalHelixTube[6, 1, 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Greg! I think the link to "here" got lost... could you attach it?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158356/4346

Comment: I was comparing your code to the analytical solution of a catenoid as a sanity check, by minimising the surface of an equivalent cylinder, but encountered an oddity. Could you take a look at the Further Question in the updates? Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Good job!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `smoothMeshRegion` from the 'Code Dump' section in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/191419/4346) to make a region that *resembles* the desired object:

```
helixPoints[l_, p_, r_, z0_:0] := Table[{r*Cos[2π/p * θ], r*Sin[2π/p * θ], z0 + θ}, {θ, 0.0, Round[l/p, 0.025p], 0.025p}]

helixRidgedTube[l_, p_, r_, r2_] :=
  Block[{helix1, helix2, n, m, mr},
    helix1 = helixPoints[l+4p, p, r, -2p];
    helix2 = helixPoints[l+4p, p, r2, -1.5p];
    
    n = Length[helix1];
    m = Round[1/0.025];
    
    mr = MeshRegion[
        Join[helix1, helix2],
        {
            Polygon[Join @@ ({{#1, #1+n, #1+n+1}, {#1, #1+n+1, #1+1}}& /@ Range[n-1])],
            Polygon[Join @@ ({{#1, #1+n-m, #1+n-m+1}, {#1, #1+n-m+1, #1+1}}& /@ Range[m+1, n-1])]
        }
    ];
    mr = DiscretizeRegion[mr, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.1}];
    
    DiscretizeRegion[
      smoothMeshRegion[mr, "VertexPenalty" -> 0.0125],
      {{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {0, l}}
    ]
  ]
```

Example:

```
helixRidgedTube[10, 1, 2, 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*Not an answer, just too big for a comment.*

I cannot reproduce OP's problems with the "overminimization". With my orignial code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158356/38178) I get the following results:

```
radius = 1.;
height = 2.;
meshsize = 0.01;

cylinder0 = DiscretizeRegion[
   ImplicitRegion[
    x^2 + y^2 == radius^2,
    {{x, - 1.1 radius, 1.1 radius}, {y, -1.1 radius, 1.1 radius}, {z, -height/2, height/2}}
    ],
   MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> meshsize}
   ];

cells = MeshCells[cylinder0, 2, "Multicells" -> True];
(*The true minimal surface, at least if h/r is small.*)
catenoid = MeshRegion[({x, y, z} |-> {Cosh[z] x, Cosh[z] y, z}) @@@ MeshCoordinates[cylinder0], cells];

(*A cylinder with the same boundary conditions as the catenoid.*)
cylinder = MeshRegion[({x, y, z} |-> {Cosh[height/2] x, Cosh[height/2] y, z}) @@@ MeshCoordinates[cylinder0], cells];

discreteMinimizer = areaGradientDescent[cylinder, 1., 20., False];

Print["Catenoid area = ", Area[catenoid]]
Show[
 discreteMinimizer,
 MeshRegion[catenoid, MeshCellStyle -> ({2, All} -> Orange)],
 PlotRange -> {All, {0, All}, All}
 ]
```

> Initial area = 19.3909
>
> Final area = 17.6773
>
> Catenoid area = 17.6773

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bend the solenoid to a torus. This is a vast field

[wikipedia helicoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicoid)

[Minimal Art](http://www.bugman123.com/MinimalSurfaces/index.html)

[Crazy bubbles](https://www.zometool.com/crazy-bubbles/)

Comment: Thanks that led me to more ideas! I'm trying the surface minimisation code here : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158356/88731 but am facing some problems generating the surface, just posted a new question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/292430/subtract-parametricregions-from-each-other if you could help with that!